# Adding a checkbox to a databound DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I'm working with DataGridView in C#. I fill it with a table from database using BindingSource. After filling the DataGridView I need to add a row of checkboxes that should be first in the table, to enable data filtering in future.

I mean: for example after clicking "Load" button I get DataGridView filled with 4 columns of data and the first row should consists of checkboxes.

I confused. I use

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
SourceDGV.Rows.Add(checkCell);
```

I mean here:
[image]

But after clicking load button it says `You can't add rows to databounded DataGridView`

Sorry if ecxeption translated wrong, I translated it from Ukrainian.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can't add a custom row of checkboxes in a databound datagridview. Make it unbound and add all your rows manually or change the logic of your interface

Comment: @Vland thanx, I know it, but isn't there any way to do it? B/c at first I don't know the number of columns I'll get

Comment: a) to add to a databound dgv you need to actually add to the datasource. b) all rows have the same datatype in the same respective columns, so as sriram says this functionaltity won't be available in a DVG alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am afraid, *there is no concept of whole rows to be of some type(checkbox in your case)* in `DataGridView`. It is other way around. You can have whole column to be of checkbox type. You'd use `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` for that.

Showing checkboxes in whole row even makes no sense for me: Assume you have data bounded `Person` object to the `DataGridView`. So there will be columns like `Name`, `Age`, `Address`. Now, on what basis you show checkbox in the row? How can a Name be converted to a `bool`(which is what checkbox needs as a value)?

One workaround I can think of would be, handle custom painting, If First row paint checkboxes over there and manually handle their click events. But am pretty sure it's not gonna be easy.

Comment: I need to have a ROW of checkboxes not the COLUMN. thank

Comment: @Daria No such feature exist out of the box. You need to roll your own.